# Jetpack compose weight modifier is inconsistent for each row

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack

I tried to create a table-like view using Jetpack compose, with weight modifiers. But the difference between row items is inconsistent.

Here is my code snippet:

```kotlin
const val firstColWeight = 2.0f
const val defColWeight = 3.0f
const val doubleColWeight = 6.0f

Column(modifier = modifier.fillMaxWidth()) {
    TableHeader()
    TableBody()
    TableFooter()
}
```

```kotlin
@Composable
fun TableHeader() {
    TableRow {
        Spacer(modifier.weight(firstColWeight))
        TableCol(
            modifier = modifier.weight(doubleColWeight)
        ) { ... }
        TableCol(
            modifier = modifier.weight(doubleColWeight)
        ) { ... }
    }
}
```

```kotlin
@Composable
fun TableBody() {
    TableRow {
        TableCol(
            modifier = modifier.weight(firstColWeight)
        ) { ... }
        TableCol(
            modifier = modifier.weight(defColWeight)
        ) { ... }
        TableCol(
            modifier = modifier.weight(defColWeight)
        ) { ... }
        TableCol(modifier.weight(defColWeight)) { ... }
        TableCol(modifier.weight(defColWeight)) { ... }
    }
}
```

```kotlin
@Composable
fun TableFooter(modifier: Modifier = Modifier) {
    TableRow(
        modifier = modifier.height(9.dp)
    ) {
        Spacer(modifier.weight(firstColWeight))
        Spacer(
            modifier
                .weight(doubleColWeight)
                .fillMaxSize()
                .background(...)
        )
        Spacer(modifier.weight(doubleColWeight))
    }
}
```

And here is the output:

[Mobile preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tjsp5.png)

As you can see there is approximately 1 dp/px difference between first and second rows

I just need to fit all columns, and remove this difference between items.

Comment: All the weights of a given layout should add up to `1.0f`.  Adjust your weight divisions and you should start seeing consistent results

Comment: Yes, But I don't want to give every item 1.0f weight. Because every item is not equal and needs to be more than 1.0f

Comment: The weights of all your child layouts should sum up to 1.0f, what I mean is if you have three children, you can have weights of 0.5f, 0.4f and 0.1f. You can't have a weight of more than 1 because it will be rounded down to 1 and all your child views will end up having the same weight.

Comment: Yeah, Thank you so much, it reduces the size of the difference, but I guess technically that's not even possible to adjust this item perfectly. Still there is a minor distance between the items. I believe that it's not as huge as it was before.

Comment: @Rafsanjani official docs use weights `1f` and `2f` as an example, so I don't think that's true https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/modifiers#weight-in-row-and-column